# tax/fee ERC20 token

Tags: solana-program, fee

I wonder if there is someway to implement tax/fee in the ERC20 for transfer to liq, marketing wallet, reflections for staking etc.

I know there is SPL token and thats not an option for us.

So is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

ERC20 is an EVM standard and is not available on Solana. SPL tokens are the token standard on Solana.

Token extensions includes an extension to add a transfer fee for SPL tokens: https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-fee